# In MySQL how do I get the total number of components if one column is related to another?

Tags: mysql

I have a few machines reporting status on hardware components. not all machines have the same amount of hardware components. I need to know the total number of components of all the machines.

I'm using this query

```
SELECT
    time AS "time",
    machine_id,
    hw_id
FROM 
    hardware
WHERE
    $__unixEpochFilter(time) AND
    component = 'gpu'
ORDER BY 
    time
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owyn3.png)

In this case, there are 9 components in total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an unique id by matching both ids.
You'll get what you need with something like:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT(machine_id+'/'+hw_id)),
  machine_id,
  hw_id
FROM hardware
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(time) AND
  component = 'gpu';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count the records returned by the filter condition in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM hardware
 WHERE $__unixEpochFilter(time) AND component = 'gpu';
```